# How to parse a string containing tags?

Tags: javascript

I get a string in the form `<red> Hello </red> World` - where red means a red string, but how do such parsers work in general, I need a simple example please))...

Comment: [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Example:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();

const htmlString = "<red> Hello </red> World";
const doc1 = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
// HTMLDocument

console.log(doc1.body.firstChild.textContent);
// Now you can make necessary edits with normal JS functions: .trim() etc.
```

Comment: Bonus: If you plan to use Regex instead in the future, please [have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11586487). Explanation is there all its glory.